# KeyError on merging Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, join, self-join

I have a table with customer purchase history. Need to populate a new column indicating first and last day of activity in the historical data.

Input Data format : `Index(['date_first', 'unique_id', 'event', 'price', 'product_id', 'category','month', 'buy', 'Bought_Before'], dtype='object')`

```
df_first=df.sort_values(by=['date']).drop_duplicates(subset='unique_id', keep='first')    
df_last=df.sort_values(by=['date']).drop_duplicates(subset='unique_id', keep='last')
#renaming date column as first_Active_Day and last_active_Day to avoid #confusion in merge
df_first.columns=['first_active_day', 'unique_id', 'event', 'price', 'product_id', 'category','month', 'buy', 'Bought_Before']

df_first.columns=['last_active_day', 'unique_id', 'event', 'price', 'product_id', 'category','month', 'buy', 'Bought_Before']

df_result = df.merge(df,df_first['first_active_day'],df_last['last_active_day'], on='unique_id')
```

I need the date - first & last active day as new columns added to the original dataframe. I was creating to intermediate dataframe to get first and last active day. Please let me know if it can be done in a easy or single step. Appreciate your help. Thanks!

Error log: (below)

File "", line 1, in 
    df_result = df3.merge(df3,df_first, on='unique_id')

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6868, in merge
    copy=copy, indicator=indicator, validate=validate)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 48, in merge
    return op.get_result()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 546, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 756, in _get_join_info
    right_indexer) = self._get_join_indexers()

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 735, in _get_join_indexers
    how=self.how)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\merge.py", line 1142, in _get_join_indexers
    if how == 'left':

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1478, in **nonzero**
    .format(self.**class**.**name**))

ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Please read carefully the parameters required for `pd.merge()` at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: I'm still trying around my head but i'm stuck with the merge. Both dataframe have the same fields. Trying to add the first field on second dataframe to all the records with same unique id in first dataframe.